# How can I show a PDF return from sftp-get from PHPSECLIB

Tags: php, pdf, phpseclib

I want to show to the user a PDF or a PNG that is in my SFTP server.
I am doing the connection with phpseclib to get the file.
How can I manipulate the file to show it in the browser?

```
    $key = new RSA();
    $key->loadKey(file_get_contents('*******'));
    $sftp = new SFTP($fsock);
    if (!$sftp->login('*******', $key)) {
        exit('Bad credentials!');
    } 


    $path = "******";
    $filename = $result[0]->filefinalname ;
    $file = $sftp->get($path . $filename);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send Content-Type and file content

```
$file = '/path/to/temp/dir/'.uniqid(rand(), true);  //temp name
file_put_contents($file,$sftp->get($path . $filename)); // save temp file

if (exif_imagetype($file))  //if this image
    header("Content-Type: image/png"); //type file png
else
    header("Content-type:application/pdf"); //type file pdf

header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); //send size
readfile($file); //send file
unlink($file); //delete temp file
```

Comment: Thx for the reply, what should be the path for the var file?

Comment: any available for write

Comment: this will redirect the user to other page to see the pdf?

Comment: i would like to redirect the user to other page to see the pdf? it is possible?